# redirect user after clicking link to sql process?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a link on a users profile called favorite. another user can click this and that user will be added to their favorites list.

The link favorite goes to favorites.php where this code processes the query:

```
<?php

require_once('includes/session.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
require('includes/_config/connection.php');


session_start();


    confirm_logged_in();




    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_favorites (user_id, favorite_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

header("Location: profile.php" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']);


?>
```

So once this process is complete my aim is to get the header to take the user back to profile.php (the previous page) whilst using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] to call the user id.

So if a users id was 16 it would redirect them  back to profile.php?id=16

Instead it just redirects to profile.php and doesnt include the id of that profile.

Can someone show me if there's a way to do this and if my way is at all right why it's not working?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure plenty of people will chime in in a second, but that code is terribly insecure, thats an SQL injection right there !

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

```
header("Location: profile.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']);
```

p.s. your code is insecure. Read about SQL injection. Switch to MySQLi or PDO

Comment: would that not take it back to the users own profile as in of the user who is logged in? i mean i want the user who is logged in to be taken back to the profile of the user whos profile they was on?

Comment: Then wouldn't `$user_to_id` contain that info?

Comment: If so, then use this `header("Location: profile.php?id=" . $user_to_id);`

Comment: yes it did, thank you i was being silly for a minute. Is there a way now i could add an echo to carry over to the previous page like this:  header("Location: profile.php?id=" . $user_to_id['user_id'] . "added=1");

Comment: and then on the profile.php page have this statement? <?
if (isset($_GET['added']) && $_GET['added'] == 1) {
   $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">This user was successfully added to your favorites.</div>"; ?>
            
            <? } ?>

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_REFERRER is not written like that, it is HTTP_REFERER (1 R). 
It contains the page the user came from so header("Location: profile.php" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']) should not work.
You should either do:

```
header("Location:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']);
```

however HTTP_REFERRER is not very reliable, you should use:

```
header("Location: profile.php?id=" . $user_to_id);
```

You should change the last option to how your website builds the links, we just assumed from your example.

Also you are setting the variable $user_id = $_GET['to'] but you are using $user_to_id to insert in the DB.

Also your code can easily be cracked, please do not use it that way, look into PDO or Mysqli functions.

Comment: Gotta love misspellings in the spec.